# Overload C++ template class method by it's template classes

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am writing a template class that manages a union of 2 classes. All the functions are pretty simple except the `Get()` functions. It looks like this:

UnionPair.hpp

```
template <class First, class Second>
class UnionPair {
 public:
  UnionPair() : state_(State::kEmpty){};
  ~UnionPair(){};

  void Reset();

  void Set(std::unique_ptr<First>&& first);
  void Set(std::unique_ptr<Second>&& second);

  template <First>
  First *Get();

  template <Second>
  Second *Get();

 private:
  enum class State { kEmpty, kFirst, kSecond } state_;
  union {
    std::unique_ptr<First> first_;
    std::unique_ptr<Second> second_;
  };
};
```

UnionPair.cpp

```
template <class First, class Second>
template <First>
First *UnionPair<First, Second>::Get() {
  return first_.get();
}

template <class First, class Second>
template <Second>
Second *UnionPair<First, Second>::Get() {
  return second_.get();
}
```

I'm trying to make the `Get()` functions template methods that can only be called with the template classes of it's instantiated `UnionPair` object, so that they can be overloaded by the template class they're called with. The above code does not compile.

My idea of how it would be called is this, but I get a compiler error when I try to call them:

```
// Definitions of structs A, B and C here

UnionPair<A, B> pair;
pair.Set(std::unique_ptr(new A()));
pair.Get<A>(); // should return a pointer to A (causes a compiler error right now)
pair.Get<C>(); // should cause a compiler error
```

I'm not really sure how to implement this method in the .cpp file, or if it's even possible. I've been reading about specialization within templates, but haven't seen any examples similar to mine, or examples where the specialization class MUST be the same as the object's template classes.

What is wrong with my usage/definition? Is what I'm trying to do possible? If not, are there any alternatives? What I DON'T want to do is have a seperate getter for First and Second like `First *GetFirst()` because that relies on the order of the classes in the object instantiation and isn't clear.

Side note: If there is a c++ library that manages the state, setting and getting of union members I'd consider using it, but I'd still like to figure my question out.

Comment: The C++ standard library class template that handles this is [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it's what I'm looking for, but I think it throws a runtime error if you try and get the wrong type from it? Would that mean there's no way to get a compiler error?

Also I can't use c++ 17 in my project, so I can't use this class. But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Putting template code into `.cpp` file like this will not work. You are making a very common mistake of writing a huge pile of code up front, and only then trying to make everything work. Professional C++ developers don't work that way. They write only a few lines of code, compile, test it, make sure they work, then write a few more lines. You should start with a template with just a few lines of code, get all of that working, then write a few more lines of template code.

Comment: I don't really see how the 30 lines of code I wrote is a 'huge pile'...

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get a compiler error when the wrong one of A or B is used, because the compiler may not know which has been set after the object was constructed, but you can get a compiler error when C is used — `get<C>(variant<A,B>)` should be an error.

Comment: Right okay that's what I'm looking for. I realize it's impossible for the compiler to know the 'state of the union' (hehe), but at least it will compiler assert if C is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can't split template code into separate `.h` and `.cpp` files:

[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)

Second, a `union`'s data is not set until runtime, so there is no way for the compiler to validate the template parameter of `Get()` at compile-time, at least not the way you want.  It is possible to validate at compile-time only whether the union could *never* convert to the specified type at all, but if it *could* convert then you can't validate that until runtime, after the `union` has been assigned.

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <class First, class Second>
class UnionPair {
 static_assert(!std::is_same<First, Second>::value, "First and Second can't be the same type");

 public:
  UnionPair();
  UnionPair(std::unique_ptr<First>&& value);
  UnionPair(std::unique_ptr<Second>&& value);
  ~UnionPair(){}

  void Reset();

  void Set(std::unique_ptr<First>&& value);
  void Set(std::unique_ptr<Second>&& value);

  template <class T>
  T* Get();

 private:
  enum class State { kEmpty, kFirst, kSecond } state_;

  union {
    std::unique_ptr<First> first_;
    std::unique_ptr<Second> second_;
  };

  template<class T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, First>::value, T*>::type
    InternalGet();

  template<class T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Second>::value, T*>::type
    InternalGet();
};

template <class First, class Second>
UnionPair<First, Second>::UnionPair()
    : state_(State::kEmpty)
{
}

template <class First, class Second>
UnionPair<First, Second>::UnionPair(std::unique_ptr<First>&& value)
    : UnionPair()
{
    Set(std::move(value));
}

template <class First, class Second>
UnionPair<First, Second>::UnionPair(std::unique_ptr<Second>&& value)
    : UnionPair()
{
    Set(std::move(value));
}

template <class First, class Second>
void UnionPair<First, Second>::Reset()
{
  if (state_ == State::kFirst)
    first_.reset();
  else if (state_ == State::kSecond)
    second_.reset();
  state_ = State::kEmpty;
}

template <class First, class Second>
void UnionPair<First, Second>::Set(std::unique_ptr<First>&& value)
{
    Reset();
    first_ = std::move(value);
    state_ = State::kFirst;
}

template <class First, class Second>
void UnionPair<First, Second>::Set(std::unique_ptr<Second>&& value)
{
    Reset();
    second_ = std::move(value);
    state_ = State::kSecond;
}

template <class First, class Second>
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, First>::value, T*>::type
  UnionPair<First, Second>::InternalGet() {
    if (state_ == State::kFirst)
        return first_.get();
    throw std::domain_error("wrong state");
}

template <class First, class Second>
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Second>::value, T*>::type
  UnionPair<First, Second>::InternalGet() {
    if (state_ == State::kSecond)
        return second_.get();
    throw std::domain_error("wrong state");
}

template <class First, class Second>
template <class T>
T* UnionPair<First, Second>::Get() {
    return InternalGet<T>();
}
```

```cpp
UnionPair<A, B> pair;
pair.Set(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A));
pair.Get<A>(); // OK
pair.Get<B>(); // runtime error
pair.Get<C>(); // compiler error
```

Comment: Yeah maybe I wasn't clear but I fully understand that it can't cause compiler errors between A and B. I was only asking that using C would cause a compiler error, which your code does. Thank you!